# Jsoup, HTTPClient, HttpURLConnection. How to get a response html, if the server always returns a 413 error code

Tags: java, android, jsoup, http-status-code-413

When sending a GET request to http://blahblahblah.com/site/Login/?domain=blahblahblah.com&request=[request string] server always response 413 error. In browser this request show html page with javascript redirect.  But in Jsoup when get this URL throwed exception. I think this is to prevent automated login.I want to get responsed html width Jsoup.

```
try{
Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://blahblahblah.com/site/Login/?domain=blahblahblah.com&request=abc123").method(Method.GET).execute();
}
catch (HttpStatusException e) {
//? What i must write here to get response
}
```

In C#/.Net HttpWebRequest Exception object contain Response and I can extract html data from it. How to do it in java / android?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
try{
        Connection response = Jsoup.connect("http://blahblahblah.com/site/Login/?domain=blahblahblah.com&request=abc123").method(Method.GET);
        response.ignoreHttpErrors(false);
        org.jsoup.Connection.Response r = response.execute();
    }
        catch (HttpStatusException e) {
//not throwed
    }
```

Comment: I would rather add condition (just 2 lines below) to accept additional code insteed of threating everything as code 200. What about redirections etc?